# Invalid Object Name 'database' stored prodedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to execute the `[dbo].[USERINFORMATION]` stored procedure.

It executes procedure successfully, but showing red squiggly line and:

> Invalid object name '[dbo].[USERINFORMATION]'

on mouse hover. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio [Version 11.0.2100.60].

**Image**

[image: Error Information]

And code:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/*
    EXEC [DBO].[USERINFORMATION] @middleName=''
*/
ALTER PROCEDURE [DBO].[USERINFORMATION]
    (@MiddleName nvarchar(50))
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @MiddleName = ISNULL(@MiddleName, '')

    SELECT 
        FirstName, MiddleName, LastName
    FROM 
        HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory
    WHERE 
        ISNULL(MiddleName,'') = @MiddleName;
```

Comment: may be it haven't created in your database just create once @mars

Comment: you used 'HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory' table means your table resides in 'HumanResources' database. It this portion is something wrong  or any mismatch your execution logic?

Comment: May be, But It showing error after reconnected. @Jonathan

Comment: it won't behave like that until you haven't executed the procedure @Mars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to refresh intellisense :

```
Edit - IntelliSense - Refresh Local Cache
```

or

```
Ctrl + Shift + R
```